# What are the risks of trusting ADDITIONAL section when they match the AUTHORITY section?

Tags: domain-name-system

If we take the following example with `dig allcosts.net @g.gtld-servers.net`:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;allcosts.net.          IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
allcosts.net.       172800  IN  NS  ns-22.awsdns-02.com.
allcosts.net.       172800  IN  NS  ns-912.awsdns-50.net.
allcosts.net.       172800  IN  NS  ns-1834.awsdns-37.co.uk.
allcosts.net.       172800  IN  NS  ns-1233.awsdns-26.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns-912.awsdns-50.net.   172800  IN  A   205.251.195.144
```

The TLD server gives an ADDITIONAL section that is not a glue record (the IP of `ns-912.awsdns-50.net` can definitely be found by a separated DNS query), but what are the risks of trusting it?

Because even if this response is actually a spoofed response (meaning the attacker actually control `ns-912.awsdns-50.net`), whatever we trust or not the ADDITIONAL section, in both case we are going to get the IP of `ns-912.awsdns-50.net` that belong to the attacker.

In terms of **security**, what would the point here not to trust the ADDITIONAL section when they match the AUTHORITY section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In terms of security, what would the point here not to trust the ADDITIONAL section when they match the AUTHORITY section?

There is no security at all regarding the `ADDITIONAL` section. In case of DNSSEC, the records in the `AUTHORITY` and `ANSWER` sections are signed, but those in `ADDITIONAL` are not. Hence the client **CAN NOT** trust the content of `ADDITIONAL` is really coming from the authoritative nameserver, it could have been modified in transit.

So even if you think the record given "matches" the `AUTHORITY` section, it could completely have been hijacked by an on-path attacker.

Most if not all DNS clients avoid using any data in `ADDITIONAL` except when there is absolutely no other way, that is when glues are needed. Technically glues are only needed when the nameservers are in-bailiwick that is at or below the domain name. Not just below the same TLD, that is just internal, as we see here, but really as in-bailiwick of the domain name queried.

Here, `ns-912.awsdns-50.net.` is not in-bailiwick of `allcosts.net.` and hence its presence in `ADDITIONAL` is both optional and better to ignore.

But let us go back in resolving your name by doing all the steps, and seeing if we need this record in the `ADDITIONAL` section and how it helps.

### Step 1

`allcosts.net` is served by:

- `ns-22.awsdns-02.com.`
- `ns-912.awsdns-50.net.`
- `ns-1834.awsdns-37.co.uk.`
- `ns-1233.awsdns-26.org.`

To get any data one of these 4 nameservers has to be contacted hence its name must be resolved. Note of course that the client needs only one of them and does not need to check all 4 of them. But let us try to resolve all those 4 names.

### Step 2a: `ns-22.awsdns-02.com.`

Domain `awsdns-02.com.` is served by:

- `g-ns-3.awsdns-02.com.`
- `g-ns-578.awsdns-02.com.`
- `g-ns-1154.awsdns-02.com.`
- `g-ns-1730.awsdns-02.com.`

Note how these 4 names are in-bailiwick to this domain, so the parent nameservers return glues (`A` and `AAAA` records) for all 4 of them, hence the name `ns-22.awsdns-02.com.` can be completely resolved, and the initial request can stop there if this was the nameserver picked. The record in the first `ADDITIONAL` section is useless here.

### Step 2b: `ns-912.awsdns-50.net.`

Domain `awsdns-50.net.` is served by:

- `g-ns-1970.awsdns-50.net.`
- `g-ns-499.awsdns-50.net.`
- `g-ns-820.awsdns-50.net.`
- `g-ns-1394.awsdns-50.net.`

Again, all bailiwick, so same conclusions as previous step.
Note how `ns-912.awsdns-50.net.` does not appear anywhere here, so again its IP address in the first `ADDITIONAL` sections is **not needed**.

### Step 2c `ns-1834.awsdns-37.co.uk.`

To cut things short, again `awsdns-37.co.uk.` is served by 4 in-bailiwick domain names, same conclusion.

### Step 2d `ns-1233.awsdns-26.org.`

Same.

### Conclusion

No matter what is done to resolve any name under `allcosts.net.`, the IP address of `ns-912.awsdns-50.net.` given in `ADDITIONAL` section **WILL NOT** be used because it is not needed. The authoritative nameservers for `awsdns-50.net.` will be queried to get the name for `ns-912.awsdns-50.net.` as the content from the parent will not be trusted.

### Postscript

But if useless, why does this record even exist?

Because `ns-912.awsdns-50.net.` was registered at relevant registry as an host object, by registrar of `awsdns-50.net.`. You can see it in whois:

```
$ whois -h whois.verisign-grs.com 'nameserver ns-912.awsdns-50.net.'
   Server Name: NS-912.AWSDNS-50.NET
   IP Address: 205.251.195.144
   Registrar: MarkMonitor Inc.
   Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.markmonitor.com
   Registrar URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
>>> Last update of whois database: 2022-01-09T07:02:41Z <<<
```

This host object is in fact useless (because this hostname is **NOT** authoritative on `awsdns-50.net.`) but maybe it was used in the past OR other domain names under `com` or `net` (as same registry) use this host object, hence it can't be deleted.

Also note here that there is no operational consequence because the IP addresses match:

```
$ dig NS-912.AWSDNS-50.NET @g-ns-1394.AWSDNS-50.NET. +short
205.251.195.144
```

Glues become a problem when the IP change on one side (ex: child) without being synchronized on the other (parent). But, again, even that here wouldn't impact anything as the `ADDITIONAL` record is not needed to resolve anything under `allcosts.net.`.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer!